# how can i close an app launched from another app?

Tags: android

I used an external player in my app to play a file.But after playing when i click the back button it is asking for saving the url.But in my app it must not be saved how to do that.
Please help me.I tried closing the player forcebly but it not worked.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what type of file are you playing? Can it be done in the background?

Comment: no,it cannot be played in background.I am playing m3u8 file.Thanks for Response.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you cannot control other applications that you have launched. If you need that type of control, you will have to implement all the functionality in your own application.

Comment: But how can i create a player code that supports m3u8 files.Because i am using 2.2 it will not support it.I need to use some external player only. Thanks for response

Comment: @rajeswari: Then don't try to close the other app. You cannot have everything that you want in life.

Comment: But i don't leave anything that i want.I will keep on trying to get that.Ok i will create my own player and try to play it.Anyway Thanks for Advise.